# bash send email after error on job

Tags: bash

I set up a cron that will run a script this script will run a command which renews lets encrypt.

```
   #!/bin/bash  
    /usr/local/sbin/certbot-auto renew --renew-hook "service nginx reload" -q >> /var/log/certbot-renew.log | mail -s "CERTBOT Renewals" test@test.com < /var/log/certbot-renew.log  
exit 0
```

This produced an email every time the cron ran but what I want is if there is an error/renewal to send an email. Ive read up that if I use `&>` this will write errors will this work if i replace  `>>` with `&>` or should I be using `2>&1` to capture both stdout and stderr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this command

```
command >>file 2>&1 | other command
```

The output is redirected to a file `>>`, then to a pipe, a tee can duplicate the output.

```
command 2>&1 | tee -a file | other command
```

Otherwise some shell accept `&>>` to redirect stdout and stderr to a file in append mode.

following command do the same, the order is important (fd1 is redirected to file and fd2 to fd1)

```
command >>file 2>&1
```